# What to do with the config files in home partition?

Tags: home-directory, partitioning, configure

If i have a separate home partition and reinstalled ubuntu will it be safe to delete all config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. Make a system backup (look [here for more info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc): you're user type 4, I would use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) )
2. Make a data backup (use whatever software you're using now, and make it an *unencrypted* backup, without password)
3. Boot the LiveCD and take the "Try" option
4. Delete everything in your current home directory except Pictures, Movies, documents)
5. Take the "install" option
6. Format the system partition (**be careful not to format the wrong one**)
7. Continue installing normally and take the *exact same* user name as you had beforehand

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files and folders inside `~/.config` folder.

This folder generally stores user specific settings. Deleting this folder will not cause any severe  harm except it will  reset all your preference
.